# fetch only User related records from other table JPA query

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to fetch the only particular `User` table records from the `RideTransaction` table.
So far I have tried the below Query

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM RideTransaction r WHERE r.user=?1 AND r.status='RIDING' OR r.status='OUTSTANDING' OR r.status='COMPLETED'")
List<RideTransaction> findRideHistoryOfUser(User user);
```

And another is

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM RideTransaction r WHERE r.user=?1 AND r.status='RIDING' OR r.status='OUTSTANDING'")
List<RideTransaction> findAllCurrentRidingOrOutstanding(User user);
```

but when I executed the above code I am getting all `RideTransaction` records instead of particular `User` records.

**RideTransaction table:**

```
@Entity
public class RideTransaction {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "ridetransection_id_generator", strategy = "com.greensaikil.entity.idgenerator.RideTransectionIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "ridetransection_id_generator")
private long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "USER", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RideTransection_User"))
private User user;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "DROP_UP_STAND", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RideTransection_Stand_DropUp"))
private Stand drop_up_stand;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "PICK_UP_STAND", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_Transection_Stand_PickUp"))
private Stand pick_up_stand;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "BICYCLE", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_Transection_Bicycle"))
private Bicycle bicycle;

private Date pick_up_time;

private Date drop_off_time;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "PICK_UP_LOCATION", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RideTransection_Location_PickUp"))
private Location pick_up_location;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "DROP_UP_LOCATION", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RideTransection_Location_DropUp"))
private Location drop_off_location;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Payment> payments = new HashSet<Payment>();

private long booking_ride_time;

private BigDecimal total_payment;

private BigDecimal remaining_outstanding;

private BigDecimal discount;

private Date booking_time;

private long total_ride_time;

private long extra_ride_time;

private BigDecimal total_rental;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private RideStatus status;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Image> image;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<RideTracking> ride_tracking = new HashSet<RideTracking>();
  //setters and getters
```

**User table:**

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", name = "USERID")
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String username;

@Column(name = "NAME")
@NotNull
private String name;

@Column(name = "USEREMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name = "USERPHONE")
private Long phone;
//setters and getters
```

Plases help me with the query to get only `User` recoreds.

Comment: hey anyone have solution

Comment: Do you have `id` of User? if yes then you can test your query with providing the ID of user rather than object. `@Query("SELECT r FROM RideTransaction r WHERE r.user.id=?1 AND r.status='RIDING' OR r.status='OUTSTANDING' OR r.status='COMPLETED'")
List<RideTransaction> findRideHistoryOfUser(Long userId);`

Comment: is this possible using passing `User` object?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of RideTransaction, you need to create a list of users, also in the beginning of your SQL query you are selecting a RideTransaction, not a user.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..i don't want `user` i want `RideTransaction` records of the particular `user`.

Comment: can you please help me with that.

Comment: hmm, if you prefer normal SQL queries you could use @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select here")

Comment: i would suggest using an id of the user, to find the matches

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="select * from RideTransaction where user.id = ?1")

Comment: and if you need more parameters, just add them aswell... like you do in regular sql

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery=true, value= "select *
from RideTransaction
where user.id in (
  select something
  from user
  where something = true
")

Answer (score 0):

It seem like a some kind of mess. What is a real tables relations? If a `User` can have more then one `RideTransaction`'s (`@OneToMane` for `RideTransaction`) then it's ok result that you've got (despite on you annotatation `@OneToOne`). If he don't so why do you declare a `List` query in a repository?
Just try youself - what will return a query `select * from RideTransaction where user = '{some_user_id}'`